# Product of Generalized Harmonic Numbers

Tags: riemann-zeta, harmonic-numbers, zeta-functions

I'm trying to sum two indipendent random variabile, in particular two zipf's law, mathematica say that the product of two generalized harmonic number $H_{p,s}$ and $H_{t,k}$, $H_{p,s}H_{t,k}$ is eqaul to:
$(\zeta(s)-\zeta(s,p+1))(\zeta(k)-\zeta(k,t+1))$ but I can't undestand how this result is possibile from the moment that I have the product of the finite sum and the $\zeta$ requires infinity sum.

Thanks.

Comment: $\zeta(s,p+1)$ is just a tail of (the infinite sum for) $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: Is the Hurwitz zeta function defined as $\zeta(s,a)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+a)^s)$ @metamorphy